# QGIS create raster from CSV and find raster index

Tags: qgis, rasterization

I have a CSV with about 2 Mio. entries with X and Y coordinates WGS84 and many attributes. The X and Y coordinate are the south west coordinate of 100 meter by 100 meter grid over a country. But the grid is not complete. 
Then I have a second CSV with X and Y coordinates WGS84 with point data.
For each point of the second CSV I want to find the appropriate raster data so I have to identify in which raster the point lies...

I tried many approaches but I can't create a raster with the first CSV.

1. If I just create a layer with the CSV I can't rasterize since vector to raster expects a shapefile.
2. When I save my layer first as a shapefile the vector to raster option does something. But how can I specify that the coordinate is the south west point of a raster? And how can I specify the the raster should be 100 by 100 meters?

Comment: Sorry, I have to use QGIS and NOT GRASS.